# Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, serialization

I'm trying to create a many to many relation between movies and users. When I save a movie I get this error:

> 2017-12-01 16:12:43.351  WARN 17328 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.movieseat.models.Movie]]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.List) not compatible with managed type (com.movieseat.model.security.User)
>
> 2017-12-01 16:12:43.354  WARN 17328 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.movieseat.models.Movie]]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.List) not compatible with managed type (com.movieseat.model.security.User)
>
> 2017-12-01 16:12:43.356  WARN 17328 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported

I had an issue:

> org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.mo‌​vieseat.model.securi‌​ty.User["authorities‌​"]->org.hibernate.co‌​llection.internal.Pe‌​rsistentBag[0]->com.‌​movieseat.model.secu‌​rity.Authority["user‌​s"]

Which I fixed by: User.java

```
@JsonManagedReference                
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name = "USER_AUTHORITY",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "AUTHORITY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")})
private List<Authority> authorities;
```

And Authority.java:

```
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authorities", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<User> users;
```

But now it seems that my Movie.java model also needs some kind of annotation. The error states:

> Can not handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.List)

So I've tried adding a @JsonBackReference to the relation in my Movie.java model:

```
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "movies")
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

But this doesn't help. Is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class User {
```

to my User.java class